# Is it possible to goto a line number in a pdf?

Tags: pdf, adobe

Just like the title says...I know you can goto page numbers and destinations, but wasnt sure about line numbers.

If so, I would need to write a program that would jump to a line number and highlight it. Is something like this even possible?

Thanks!

**EDIT**

Forgot about the highlighting part.

Comment: What exactly does this have to do with Java or ColdFusion?

Comment: Absolutely nothing. I would be writing the program in coldfusion or java. I also posted this with an adobe tag. Wasnt sure where this question should've been posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am 99% sure that the highlighting thing is not possible.
About "going to" a line number, there is no concept of line number in PDF, however, goto-actions in PDF can use a destination object as target, and a destination object can specify a x,y coordinate of the destination page to be set as left-top corner in a viewer (although viewers can ingore this parameter). Take a look on "Destination Dictionaries" in the PDF specification for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I kind of figured that was the case but just wanted to verify.